# python pip install failures

Tags: python, pip, ubuntu-14.04

i am trying to install a library `pynput` using 
**sudo pip install pynput**

but i am getting this error log. This has been happening with any other python package. everything used to work fine suddenly these errors are appearing i tried to copy error log from

**~/.pip/pip.log**

and this is what i have:

```
 Using version 1.4 (newest of versions: 1.4, 1.3.10, 1.3.9, 1.3.8.1, 1.3.7, 1.3.6, 1.3.5, 1.3.4, 1.3.3, 1.3.2, 1.3.1, 1.3, 1.2, 1.1.7, 1.1.6, 1.1.5, 1.1.4, 1.1.3, 1.1.2, 1.1.1, 1.1, 1.0.6, 1.0.5, 1.0.4, 1.0.3, 1.0.2, 1.0.1, 1.0, 0.6, 0.5.1, 0.5, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2)
Cleaning up...
  Removing temporary dir /tmp/pip_build_root...
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 278, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1198, in prepare_files
    do_download,
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1376, in unpack_url
    self.session,
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 546, in unpack_http_url
    resp = session.get(target_url, stream=True)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 467, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 237, in request
    return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 455, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 558, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/adapters.py", line 330, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.7.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 562, in urlopen
    body=body, headers=headers)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.7.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 387, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1017, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1051, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1013, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 864, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 826, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.7.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 145, in connect
    match_hostname(self.sock.getpeercert(),
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.7.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 313, in getpeercert
    for value in get_subj_alt_name(x509)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.7.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 94, in get_subj_alt_name
    asn1Spec=general_names)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyasn1/codec/ber/decoder.py", line 825, in __call__
    stGetValueDecoder, self, substrateFun
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyasn1/codec/ber/decoder.py", line 391, in valueDecoder
    r.verifySizeSpec()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyasn1/type/base.py", line 252, in verifySizeSpec
    def verifySizeSpec(self): self._sizeSpec(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyasn1/type/constraint.py", line 32, in __call__
    '%s failed at: \"%s\"' % (self, sys.exc_info()[1])
ValueConstraintError: ConstraintsIntersection(ConstraintsIntersection(), ValueSizeConstraint(1, 64)) failed at: "ValueSizeConstraint(1, 64) failed at: "SubjectAltName().setComponents(GeneralName(componentType=NamedTypes(NamedType('otherName', AnotherName(componentType=NamedTypes(NamedType('type-id', ObjectIdentifier('<no value>')), NamedType('value', ...........
```

Comment: What's the error? Did you research its meaning?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt i have attached the error log but it gave no clear results in google when i searched for it

Comment: @anekix were you able to fix that problem? all of a sudden I encounter the same error

Comment: @Variant no i couldn't fix that yet :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A similar issue exists [here](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/1488).

The problem seems to be that the PyPI certificate now has more than 64 SAN names on it, breaking the hardcoded maximum in older versions of requests.

Make sure you have recent versions of both the requests and urllib3 modules.

Comment: thanks but how to upgrade requests when pip itself is not working

Comment: You can try "python -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel".  There are other options at https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/

Comment: i get the same error on running the above command. i should first upgrade `pip` or `requests`?

Answer (score 2):

You need to update pip. Just enter this command

```
curl  https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | sudo python
```

After update `bash -l`

That's it.

Answer (score 1):

I got it working by.
removing `requests`, `urllib` manually from

`/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`

and reinstalling requests with `sudo easy_install requests`

then `sudo easy_install pip==9.0.1`

Comment: That's essentially what I said in my answer. :)

Comment: @OregonJim yes thankyou so much I have accepted your answer as correct one.just thought of adding the steps using easy_install :)

Answer (score 0):

Try updating pip using

```
sudo -H pip2 install --upgrade pip
```

command.

Comment: i get same class of errors if i try : `sudo pip install --upgrade pip`

Comment: Did you try the above command? Where we set home using sudo -H

Comment: the above command gave `You must give at least one requirement to install (see "pip help install")` so i tried `sudo -H pip2 install --upgrade pip` but same error as in my question

Comment: Oh sorry! a typo. my bad. https://askubuntu.com/questions/712339/how-to-upgrade-pip-to-latest    .Could you try the second method listed here?

Comment: i tried from the link you said.but i get the same error in error log

Answer (score 0):

Below solution **worked** for me.

1. Uninstall pip2
2. Install pip2 using PyPI (Refer 'Install pip From PyPI' section in https://www.howtodojo.com/2016/03/install-use-pip-ubuntu-14-04/)
   Note: Install from ubuntu repository didn't work in my case.
3. Then I no longer got ValueConstraintError while installing any module using pip2 (ex: pip2 install invoke)